# How can I copy pictures to the Gallery?

Tags: gallery, images

I have some pictures in a directory on my phone. How can I make them appear inside the picture Gallery?

Comment: It should automatically pick them up. Is it not?

Comment: @Al: no it isn't. should I expect it to happen immediately?

Comment: @Nathan Have you rebooted? Android normally scans for new media on startup.

Comment: Indeed it should be automatic. Which phone do you have?

Comment: @Dr: Samsung Galaxy S

Comment: You can also 'encourage' the phone to rescan the SD card by unmounting and remounting it, or using a little app from the Market called 'SDRescan' (which essentially does the same thing).

Comment: @Matt: why don't you put that as an answer to the question then? :-)

Comment: @Nathan: Your wish, my command, etc etc :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can 'encourage' the phone to rescan the SD card by unmounting and remounting it (Settings > SD & Phone Storage), or by using a little app from the Market called '[SDrescan](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bero.sdrescan)' (which essentially does the same thing).

Answer (score 1):

Did you put these files in the directory, or did one of your apps?

If an app did it, it might have dropped a ".nomedia" file in there too. The presence of this file keeps android from adding the pictures  the gallery.

Use a file explorer like Astro to double check for the .nomedia file. You can safely manually delete it.

Comment: Dropbox put them in. I changed the settings of the file explorer to show me hidden files, and there was no .nomedia file there.

Answer (score 1):

Today I had the same question. I copied a directory full of pictures from an SD card to the Android's phone internal storage, using a downloaded File Manager app, then removed the SD card. In the gallery, the pictures were not found, even after reboot. But after a minute or five, the pictures started to appear in the Gallery.

My conclusion is that Gallery will scan most if not all directories that are likely to hold pictures, but that it may take a while.